# How can the expectation be equal to the probability?

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory

I'm going through David Williams' 'Probability with Martingales' and in it he states the definition of expectation as the Lebesgue integral relative to $\mathbb{P}$: $$\mathbb{E}(X) := \int_{\Omega}Xd\mathbb{P}$$ Then he states that: "We also define $\mathbb{E}(X)$ for $X \in (m\mathfrak{F})^{+}$ (by which he means $X$ is a non-negative, $\mathfrak{F}$-measurable function). In short, $\mathbb{E}(X) = \mathbb{P}(X)$"

I don't understand this final part; how can an expected value of the random variable be equal to a probability which lies between $0$ and $1$?

**EDIT:**

I think it could be a notation issue. That's my inkling - $\mathbb{P}(X)$ in itself doesn't even make sense. But my next questions would be:

1. Am I right?
2. Why would you define expectation like this?

Comment: That doesn't make sense as written. Where they agree is that the expectation of the indicator function of a measurable set is the probability of that set.

Comment: @Ian Edited question

Comment: I think it is a notation as explained in the chapter 5.0: $\mu(f)$ is a shorthand for $\int_S f d\mu$.

Comment: Thank you very much. Relieved to know this!

Comment: @Kolmo Oh so the $\mathbb P(X)$ here is the $\mu(f)$ there? As in $$\mathbb P(X) = \int_{\Omega} X d\mathbb P$$ just as $$\mu(f) = \int_S f d\mu$$ ?

Comment: @Kolmo What about [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kUxpK.png) ? It seems like $\mathbb P$ is supposed to take events as arguments but later takes random variables as arguments

Comment: @BCLC, your edits are beyond just formatting or clarification. If you want to ask your own question, you should start it rather than modifying the existing ones considerably.

Comment: @zhoraster OP is asking about $\mathbb P$ so I am providing the context by pointing out certain parts in textbook?

Comment: @BCLC, what I mean is written in my comment. The original question was already answered by Kolmo in a comment (which is not a desirable way of answering, but anyway). If you have your own questions, ask them in separate posts. And I don't see a reason to continue this discussion in comments.

Comment: @BCLC If you again mis-edit this post (and that would be for the third time), please be aware that these disruptive actions will be signalled to the mods.

Comment: MystJ, are you satisfied even after I pointed out the PP in the other parts? cc @zhoraster

Answer (score 2):

So $\mathbb P$ takes events as arguments, but we use notation '$\mathbb P(X)$' where $X$ is in $\mathscr L^1(\Omega, \mathscr F, \mathbb P)$ to mean

$$\int_{\Omega} X d\mathbb P$$

Previously in book:

Given measure space $(S, \Sigma, \mu)$

$\mu(A)$ is measure of $A$ if $A \in \Sigma$

$\mu(f) = \int_S f d\mu$ if $f \in \mathscr L^1(\Omega, \mathscr F, \mathbb P)$

Therefore, when we say '$\mathbb P(X)$' in Chapter 6, this is meant in the sense of Chapter 5 where we extend the notion of a function on measurable sets (in probability: events) to a function on measurable functions (in probability: random variables). As it turns out, '$\mathbb P(X)$', as defined in the measure theory sense of Chapter 5, is equivalent to the probability sense we know it as '$\mathbb E(X)$'

---

Also

$$f\mu(A) = \mu(f1_A) = \int_S f1_A d\mu$$

So if $h \in \mathscr L^1(\Omega, \mathscr F, \mathbb P)$

$$f\mu(h) = \mu(fh) = \int_S fh d\mu$$

Answer (score 0):

The expectation of a binary payoff, of the style $b=1$ if $X$ higher (lower) than a cutoff $k$, and $0$ otherwise, $\mathbb{E}(b) \in [0,1]$, constitutes a probability since it is equal to $\mathbb{P}(X \geq k)$ (or $<$).

Comment: NNT, I edited the question

Comment: NNT, I think the question is on notation. like making sense out of plugging in a random variable into the function on measurable sets. of course the answer is that a random variable is a measurable function and then there's a definition in previous chapter of plugging in a measurable function into a function on measurable sets